# Regex show multiple choices but count as one

Tags: php, regex, string, sqlite, character

I need to find one of x or y in every line, something like: ^.*(x|y){1}.*$
it should find lines 3 and 4 only, but it shows 1 and 2 as well, what i don't want.

```
who said that x and y are important (2)
you have a y (2)
But here i have one x (1)
you have nothing (1)
```

Thanx for help

I tried to find the exact char count in every line. but some chars have multiple shapes

Comment: Can you provide the exact formatted string you are matching against, and the exact expected result?

Comment: Its in arabic and much complicated. i wanted to make it here simpler.

Comment: e.g. أ Or إ or ا  are the same. it should not find a sentence of the same character more than 1 time even if it has multiple shapes

Comment: this line has one of the 3 shapes a posted: لكل نب(إ) مستقر وسوف تعلمون . but this one here has 3 shapes صدقة يتبعه(ا) (أ)ذى و(ا)لله غنى حليم

Comment: @Pandau x and y are there in lines 1 and 2 as well. Hence, it returns all 1-3 lines.

Comment: Line 4 has neither. Why should it match?

Comment: what exact you are trying to match?

Comment: اذا الأشكال دي انحلت مشكلتها فأي أشكال تانية حاتكون نفس الشيئ

Comment: I need either x or y one time in a line not both of them

Comment: @nice_dev only line 3 and 4 have either x or y

Comment: Do you need to find all strings that contain `x` or `y` but not both at the same time? Do x and y represent a single character?

Comment: @Pandau `you have nothing (1)` Please tell me where is `x` or `y` here.

Comment: @jared yap that's what I need

Comment: @nice_dev sorry, it's my first time posting here.

Comment: @nice_dev line1: who said that (x) and (y) are..

Comment: @Pandau In your present input, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(([^y|x]*x[^y|x]*)|([^x|y]*y[^x|y]*))$/gm
```

Explanation: match the string that starts with any amount of non-y and non-x characters followed by an x character that is followed by any non-y  and non-x characters. Or match a string with the same rules for `y`.

Working example here: https://regex101.com/r/D5VUlc/2

Comment: thx for help, but it should match line 3 and 4. Line2 has 2y

Comment: Line 4 has nothing. Line 2 does not have two standalone `y`'s. Please specify your exact requirements.

Comment: (y)ou have a (y). I didn't say standalone. I need only 1y or 1x

Comment: If you dont' care about word boudaries, and need lines that contain exact one occurrence of `x` without any `y` occurrencies, or exact one occurrence of `y` without any `x` occurrencies try this: `/^(([^y|x]*x[^y|x]*)|([^x|y]*y[^x|y]*))$/gm`